# Nginx doesn't follow symlink properly

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, symlink, deployment

I'm trying to automate my deployment process and I'm having this strange issue.
Every new version of my web app is placed in `/var/www/releases/{timestamp}`. After I execute `git clone` into that directory I make a symlink to `/var/www/current`. Then I execute `service nginx reload`. The approach is used by many deployment tools and is well thought.

The problem is that when I go to a web browser to see the changes and hit refresh multiple times, I can see both releases (current and previous) alternating for several seconds/minutes. After a while it stabilizes on the current version only.

Does anybody know what might be causing this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some cache in your nginx. Have you turned on your nginx cache? This thread may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx

Comment: Setting `sendfile off` solved this issue, thank you @imapollo

Comment: I've set `sendfile off` in the `server` directive, restarted nginx and still have this problem